# Add trial period to app. Shall I use Timer or DispatchQueue in Swift (iOS)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, xcode

That application I am making has 5 days trial period. Please tell me what is the best way to show alert or something after trial period is over. I want to use the method which drains less battery and is more efficient. Following are two ideas.

**Timer:**

```
Let fiveDays = 5 * 24 * 60 * 60    
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: fiveDays, repeats: false, block: { (timer) in print("Hi!")})
```

**DispatchQueue**

```
Let fiveDays = 5 * 24 * 60 * 60 
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + fiveDays, execute: {
    self.functionToCall()
})
```

Please suggest:

> 1. What is the best approach? Is it **Timer** or **DispatchQueue**
> 2. Why is it the best approach?

Comment: Neither a Timer or DispatchQueue will work.  Both approaches will stop working when the user switches to another app, or kills a background app.  An approach that doesn't work is not best.

Comment: Be aware that an app with a trial period is likely to be rejected under review guideline 2.2; You could use an autorenewing subscription IAP with a free trial period

Comment: @Paulw11 Could you please post the exact link, that would be really helpful. Thank you.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#app-completeness

Answer (score 1):

It would be a lot better to do this on the server-side. Simply register the device id onto the server and then, when your app start check whether its been 5 days since that device has registered. This would be the best approach to accomplish what you want to do.

Comment: No, but there is no server side of the app.

Comment: @AyeshaKhan If you don't  have any server, you can use Firebase or some other cloud storage like Firebase to store user install info and check from there for trial period.

Comment: You can use CloudKit as your server database.

Answer (score 1):

Set the date in `UserDefaults` at first launch.
After every launch compare the dates.
And my advice to you is that do the check on server side.

Comment: Well, if app doesnt have server side then user could simply un-install and re-install the app to overcome validation of trial period. This could be the case if UserDefaults are being used.

Comment: explain how well it suits user's conditions

Comment: Use timer or dispatchqueues?

Comment: I think timers dont work after app gets terminated. So how would you manage time calculation after the app would get killed. Its better to store the first launch date in UserDefaults and then calculate the duration on each launch thereafter.

Answer (score 1):

Neither one would work without on-device persistence, and neither is a good idea even with persistence.

The best way would be to save an initial start date to the device the first time the user logs in, and then check that date each subsequent log in to see if 5 days has passed yet.

Comment: Use Timer or DispatchQueue?

Comment: No. Just save an `NSTimeInterval` to `NSUserDefaults`

Answer (score 1):

Both the approaches you wish to use are not much useful.
You can do this with 2 approaches.

1) Store all the user information in your server but in order to do that you may need to register your user first and then on the app side you may disable some feature or whole app depending your requirements when trial period expires.

2) If you dont want to do it using your backend server then you can store device unique id in device keychain and later retrieve it if user uninstalls and then installs again, this way you can find whether use deleted the app earlier or not and check your trial period.

Thanks

Comment: Keychain storage will no longer work with the newest (or next) version of iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Following are the options to track time period of application. But both of these ways can easily be demolished by re-installing/changing device time.

1. Keychain (persists even if user re-install application)
2. UserDefaults (reset on re-install of application)

**Solution**: In order to overcome above mentioned issues, we can track trial time period by keeping record in `Keychain` and taking `time online reference`, this requires us to make an API call(There are number of such online services that provides you with exact server time with API hit).